# In iOS in Swift, how to hide away dependent frameworks in a framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcode8

I'm looking for a solution where I can develop a framework, X, that depends on framework Y. And the consumer of X should never know about Y.

Currently, I'm building an umbrella framework. That is, Y is included in the building of X via a `Copy Files` build phase. This results in the following framework bundle:

```
X.framework/
  Frameworks/
    Y.framework/
      Y (binary)
  X (binary)
```

The problem I'm running into is distribution. From my testing, if a user copies X into their project, the compiler will build ok. But when they run it on device, they'll get this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Y.framework/Y
>     Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/ED17DA9C-3A17-44EA-B944-22B1387EB9F7/test.app/Frameworks/X.framework/X
>
> Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/ED17DA9C-3A17-44EA-B944-22B1387EB9F7/test.app/Frameworks/X.framework/Frameworks/Y.framework/Y: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00377000, size=0x00248000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/ED17DA9C-3A17-44EA-B944-22B1387EB9F7/test.app/Frameworks/X.framework/Frameworks/Y.framework/Y

To resolve this error, the user must also specifically copy Y into their project. We'd have to resolve this through documentation.

Ideally, the user doesn't need to know about Y at all. Further, not sure how well this setup plays into CocoaPods and Carthage distribution. Is it possible to not expose Y to the user?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried along with the errors you have. Please be *specific*, and since it's Swift, the version(s) you are using. Something we can duplicate!

Comment: @dfd thanks for the feedback, added more details.

Comment: It kind of looks like it found your Y framework but at a different path?

Comment: Still, code might help. It's rather impossible (for me at least) to deal with Xs and Ys. Instead, imports with names, targets with names...

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what's wrong. You're host application, `test.app`, can't load the library `Y.framework/Y` which you have referenced in `X.framework/X`. Both frameworks are dynamic. Being dynamic, they will be loaded at runtime and, as the name suggests, dynamically linked. This explains the error. The app is trying to load `Y.framework/Y` at runtime and because it's not present the error occurs.

At the time this question was asked there was no way to do what you wanted in a swift dynamic library. Since Xcode 9 though, swift static libraries are available. It is possible to statically link a library into a dynamic library to effectively hide it. So if you are the author of both libraries you can achieve the setup you describe above.

There are possible issues with this approach though. If the inner library is also available to be included in an app by itself, and that inner library defines reference types then when effectively two copies of the library are included in an app, one hidden in the dynamic library, a warning will be logged stating that two the symbols for the reference type were defined in two places.

Comment: @Eric is there a way to do it without having the "duplicate symbols" error? meaning If I have 2 frameworks who share the same code base (I can compile it as a static lib) which I don't want to expose to the client(let's say Logger/Network manager), Is there a proper solution for this?
By using Carthage/Cocoapods I still need to make those headers public so my "external" framework can import